# MySqlDataAdapter with GroupBy sql string returns empty content

Tags: c#, mysql, group-by

I use following SQL Statment to get Values from a database. 
But it always retuns DBNull values instead of the data:

```
SELECT FTCalendar FROM T_Feiertage2 GROUP BY FTCalendar ORDER BY FTCalendar
```

My C# Code:

```
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, connection);
        adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);
```

As seen in the debugger the values

```
dataSet.Tables["T_Feiertage2"].Rows[0]["FTCalendar"]  
dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
```

are DBNull (not null (they exist but are empty)) although

```
 dataSet.Tables["T_Feiertage2"].Rows.Count = 7
```

as expected.

But when I try the same SQL Statement in the Database directly it returns sensible values.

Where is my mistake ???

Comment: So is `strSQL` = `"SELECT FTCalendar FROM T_Feiertage2 GROUP BY FTCalendar ORDER BY FTCalendar"`? What type is `FTCalendar`?

Comment: just the name of the column

Comment: sorry, I should read better. It must be kind of text

Comment: dataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0].DataType  = {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}

Comment: Can you select other data from the database or is this your first try? Does it work without `Group By`(because of your title):  `SELECT FTCalendar FROM T_Feiertage2 ORDER BY FTCalendar`?

Comment: Yes I can select other Data from the same Table. I can select the whole table and everything. Ohter SQL Statements work fine. The problem occures first time with the "group by" component.

Comment: I even can get data from the column "FTCalendar" in other sql statements that dont use "group by"

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a instance of the DataSet first?

```
  DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
```

Did you update your component? I means, your provider? You can do this using nuget packages... maybe, they have some issue with the currently version that you are using..

Comment: If there is no instance you get a `NullReferenceException` at `adapter.Fill(dataSet, tableName);`.

Comment: You can use your component from Nuget, instead of use the reference of the .NetFramework providers.

Comment: Just write Mysql.Data in the nuget and remove your older reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. 
There were some rows with empty data in the database. And I did not see it at first. 
So I am sorry. 
The question is of no help for others. 
So admins can delete them.

Thanks for your help and answers. 
And sorry for your effort.